# Cherry pick up option having issues in svn

Tags: svn

I was trying to do an up merge of one revision from my branch to trunk. Initially when I tried the changes got applied to trunk and one file had a conflict, while trying to resolving the conflict, I did some mistake. So I deleted the code, did a fresh check out of trunk from repository and started the process again. When I tried to merge the revision I am seeing the changes are not getting applied. I could see not files are getting merged Is there any problem with what I am doing?

Also in cherry pick up option I could see some revisions are getting skipped. Just want to understand how svn will take the changes, If I have modified one file in two revisions say r1 and r2 and If I try to do up-merge of r2 will r1 changes also be merged as I have done changes on top of r1 in r2?  Also If I try merge R1 changes will R2 changes be skipped? Also I give both revision in merge what will happen?

Also How can I know whether this revision has already merged to trunk other than comparing the code?

Regards,
Adam

Answer (score 0):

When you do cherry-picking revisions in SVN,  you have to be careful with dependency. Similar to your example case in question, let's assume the following scenario:

- R1: modified fileA.txt
- R2: modified fileA.txt
- R3: modified fileB.txt

Then when you cherry pick in different ways as follow:

- R2 only - wont work because there is dependent revision prior to it for the same file
- R1 + R2 - will work because all prior dependent revision(s) are picked as well
- R3 only - will work because no prior dependent exists.

So dependency check comes down to finding out which revisions involve modification to the same file(s) in another prior revisions. Manually checking can be confusing and error-prone when you have many revisions with many files modified in your cherry-pick. I would recommend using algorithm check for dependency in cherry-picking as we have implemented in our release management software (http://syncrelease.com/tour)